# Getting 400 error code from Axios request while implementing token revocation flow for Apple Sign-In in Firebase

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement the token revocation flow for Apple Sign-In in Firebase, following the instructions given in this GitHub repository: https://github.com/jooyoungho/apple-token-revoke-in-firebase. However, when I try to run the code to get the Refresh Token, I keep receiving a 400 error code from the Axios request.

Here's the code I'm trying to implement:

```
exports.getRefreshToken = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

  const axios = require('axios');
  const qs = require('qs')

  const code = request.query.code;
  const client_secret = makeJWT();

  let data = {
      'code': code,
      'client_id': clientId,
      'client_secret': client_secret,
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
  }

  return axios.post(`https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token`, qs.stringify(data), {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
  })
  .then(async res => {
      const refresh_token = res.data.refresh_token;
      response.send(refresh_token);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    response.send(error);
    functions.logger.log('Error getting refresh token', {error})
  })

});
```

I am using the app bundleID for client_id

The authorizationCode in my app is formatted in this manner

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.x.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I am using @awesome-cordova-plugins/sign-in-with-apple to re auth the user right before getting the refresh token so the authCode should still be valid.

Comment: the error message i am getting from axios looks like this message: "Request failed with status code 400",name: "AxiosError",stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400

"code":"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my main issue. I renamed the AuthKey_XXXX.p8 file do not do that. I have the cloud function working locally.